# Join on month if available else join on latest month

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a scenario here

Table A:

```
---------------------------------------------
Req        CreatedMth     Amount      By
---------------------------------------------
R1         201806         100         John  
R2         201805         200         Mary
```

Table B:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
User         AvailableinOrgMonth            Position
-----------------------------------------------------
John         201805                         P1  
John         201806                         P1  
John         201807                         P1  
John         201808                         P1  
Mary         201803                         P1  
Mary         201804                         P1
```

Expected results:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Req    CreatedMth     Amount      By     AvailableinOrgMonth       Position
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
R1     201806         100         John   201806                    P1  
R2     201805         200         Mary   201804                    P1
```

The logic here is, if user is available in table B for that month, join on that and user. Else find the latest month in which user is available and join on that.
Now you might say if Mary is not available in 201805 how can she create a request. The issue in table B is every day the data for the current month is replaced and last day of the month data is kept. So mary might have created request on 2018-05-02 but left on 2018-05-31 so as a monthly data she wont appear in 201806.
I wrote the below query

```
SELECT
  A.Req, 
  A.CreatedMth, 
  A.Amount, 
  A.By, 
  A.AvailableinOrgMonth, 
  A.Position 
FROM 
  Table A as A 
  LEFT JOIN (
    Select 
      *, 
      MAX(AvailableinOrgMonth) OVER (PARTITION BY user) as Maxmonth 
    FROM 
      Table B
  ) B ON A.By = B.User 
  AND (
    A.CreatedMth = B.AvailableinOrgMonth 
    OR (
      A.CreatedMth != B.AvailableinOrgMonth 
      AND B.AvailableinOrgMonth = B.Maxmonth
    )
  )
```

This returns

```
Req    CreatedMth     Amount      By     AvailableinOrgMonth       Position
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
R1     201806         100         John   201806                    P1  
R1     201806         100         John   201808                    P1(dup)  
R2     201805         100         Mary   201804                    P1
```

How to get the Correct result.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need the req that is valid on or before the date.  Let me assume that `B` has a unique identifier for each row.  Then you can get the corresponding row using a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*,
       (select b.b_id
        from b
        where b.user = a.by and b.AvailableinOrgMonth <= a.CreatedMth 
        limit 1
       ) as b_id
from a;
```

Then you can get additional information with another `join`:

```
select a.*, b.*
from (select a.*,
             (select b.b_id
              from b
              where b.user = a.by and b.AvailableinOrgMonth <= a.CreatedMth 
              limit 1
             ) as b_id
      from a
     ) a left join
     b
     on a.b_id = b.b_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```
SELECT T1.*,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS(
                        SELECT 1
                        FROM T2
                        WHERE T1.[By] = T2.[User]
                              AND
                              T1.CreatedMth = T2.AvailableinOrgMonth
                       )
           THEN T1.CreatedMth
           ELSE MAX(T2.AvailableinOrgMonth) 
           END AvailableinOrgMonth,
       T2.Position
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.[By] = T2.[User]
GROUP BY
         T1.Req,
         T1.CreatedMth,
         T1.Amount,
         T1.[By],
         T2.Position;
```

**Returns:**

```
+-----+------------+--------+------+---------------------+----------+
| Req | CreatedMth | Amount |  By  | AvailableinOrgMonth | Position |
+-----+------------+--------+------+---------------------+----------+
| R1  |     201806 |    100 | John |              201806 | P1       |
| R2  |     201805 |    200 | Mary |              201804 | P1       |
+-----+------------+--------+------+---------------------+----------+
```

However, I don't know from where you get `100` Amount for both rows

Comment: Sorry that was a copy mistake. I have edited it. I will try this out. Thanks